# ResourceTimelineMonth : Wish to start the display on the 1st Monday of the month and end on a full week (Sunday)

Tags: fullcalendar

On my ResourceTimelineMonth view, for the month of May 2024 for example, I would like the display to be the 1st Monday of the month (06/05/2024) and the last date to be the Sunday of the last week of the month (02/ 06/2024).

I tried to play with the firstday parameters, to customize the number of days with a resourceTimeline view but the range of days to display varies depending on the month... see example.
How to do ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.